# How does i implement SAML SSO with Azure AD

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Can anyone suggest which is best idp that we can integrate with Azure AD for SAML SSO.
My goal is need to use Azure AD credentials for all my business application.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! So, what did you try so far to solve your issue? What exact error you observe? Please understand (stackoverflow.com/help/asking) that StackOverflow is not a place to ask questions "how do I ...?".

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD, AAD is the IDP.

You are the RP.

Any SAML provider can be used e.g. ADFS, PingFederate, Shibboleth etc.

You want "Azure AD credentials for all my business application". Is your business application .NET, Java ... ? Does it have to use SAML? Could it use WS-Federation, OpenID Connect, OAuth ... ?

Is your business application one you wrote yourself or is it SaaS - many of these are already integrated with AAD.